# XPath, Java and serialized xml

Tags: java, xpath

Assuming some xml like

```
<foo>
  <bar>test</bar>
</foo>
```

Evaluating an expression with returnType = String like

```
/foo/bar
```

will return "test". However, I'd like to get the serialized xml instead, so something like

```
<bar>test</bar>
```

should be returned instead. As I can not check for the returnType in java's xpath implementation (xerces), I cannot simply get an object as result and if it indeed is a node, convert it to serialized xml.

**Note: I don't know whether the expression will actually return a node, a string, a number or whatever so I cannot provide an appropriate return type to the eval function except string which, as my problem states, returns the text content and not the serialized xml.**

So I am curious -> is there either a java- or (preferred) a xpath-way (function?) to get serialized xml for type string instead of the text children of the selected node?

thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 1):

use the xpath return type XPathConstants.NODE and then you can serialize the returned Node yourself.

Comment: thanks, however I don't know whether the expression returns a node or something else. Edited my original posting to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you are right to observe that it's difficult to discover the return type of the result; this is a real design weakness of JAXP.

If it's a problem to you, consider using Saxon's s9api interface, which returns XdmValue objects whose type you can interrogate; you also get XPath 2.0 access as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Kay answered, this is difficult in JAXP (the native Java interface).

In Mr Kay's Saxon library's s9api API (see [*Evaluating XPath Expressions using s9api*](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html)), once you've called [`XPathSelector.evaluate()`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathSelector.html#evaluate()) or [`XPathSelector.evaluateSingle()`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathSelector.html#evaluateSingle()) you can get the XML serialisation by calling  [`XdmValue.toString()`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmValue.html#toString()).

However, if the XPath selected an attribute (e.g. `//@name`) you will still get the XML serialisation, e.g. `name="value"`. You can call [`XdmItem.getStringValue()`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmItem.html#getStringValue()), but for elements that method will return the same values you're already seeing - the textual content of the element, not the serialisation. I've posted separately about how to [distinguish between attributes and elements returned from Saxon s9api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971101/how-to-distinguish-between-attribute-and-element-nodes-returned-from-a-saxon-xpa/37971102#37971102).